# php - simpleXML put same nodes into array

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml, nodes

I am reading an XML file using PHPs simple xml.  I Loop through each category node to display the containing node data depending on what category has been selected, thus showing subcategories.  I need to detect when a category has no subcategories somehow.  What I need is to maybe get all of the parent_id nodes into an array and then see if cat_id is in the array to detect if it has any dependants.

```
$cat_xml = simplexml_load_file(XML_PATH.'categories/'. $clientID . '.xml');

            //get all the categories and go through each one
            foreach($cat_xml as $cat){  
                if ( //WHAT GOES HERE?? ){
                    //display if cat is top level or has been selected 
                    if ($cat->parentID == $cat_parent_id){
                        //check product isn't set to hidden
                        if ($cat->visible == 1){
                            echo '<div class="catbox">';
                                echo "<a href=\"index.php?pageID=$pageID&cat_parent_id=$cat->id&cat_name=$cat->Name\"> $cat->Name </a><br />";
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '<p>There are no sub categories.</p>';
                }
            }
```

[EDiT]
The XML is below and I need to get an array of "parentID" values

```
<categories> <category> <id>740073</id> <Name>Leetee Cat 1</Name> <parentID>0</parentID> <Description><![CDATA[Charlotte Balbier Weddinhg <em>dresses</em>,<strong> blah blah blah!!<br /> </strong>]]></Description> <imageURL>alice-charlotte-balbier-english-tea-party-collection-2011.jpg</imageURL> <sequence>0</sequence> <visible>1</visible> </category>
```

Comment: please show a snippet of the XML and clarify what exactly you need to parse from it.

Comment: Ive added the XMl to the original question - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XPath](http://us.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) can be used to search for categories that contain a parent id of the current category.

```
foreach($cat_xml as $cat) {
    $cat_id = intval($cat->id);
    // Find categories that call this one their parent
    $child_cats = $cat_xml->xpath("/categories/category[parentID/text()={$cat_id}]");
    if (!empty($child_cats)){
        //display if cat is top level or has been selected 
        if ($cat->parentID == $cat_parent_id){
            // ....
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p>There are no sub categories.</p>';
    }
}
```